# Using a string as a directory from excel to change the image in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jxl

I feel that's the most accurate title ever created and says exactly what I need. I am making a card game in Java and have loaded all the cards stats into a spreadsheet. I'm using the JXL api to read the spreadsheet and grab the stats for each card from its respective cell in the spreadsheet and store them in a Deck object and everything works really great there, but when I try to use the string that the getImage() returns, I keep getting a null pointer and I can't figure out why. I'll post everything I think is relevant, please let me know if more is needed.

The first part is from the class LoadCards that loads the spreadsheet and attaches the data to a Deck object. Note: i only have one attempt here as a test to make sure it's working and it's not.

```
public class LoadCards 
{
public Deck LoadCards()
{
    Workbook cardList  = null;
    try
    {
        cardList  = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\DC Card Game\\src\\DCCardGame\\resources\\CardList.xls"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        String message = "The file titled CardList.xls was not found.";
        String title = "File Not Found";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (BiffException ex) 
    {
        String message = "File must have an extension of .xls";
        String title = "Incompatible CardList File";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }        
        Sheet typeSheet = cardList.getSheet(0);
        Sheet equipmentSheet = cardList.getSheet(1);
        String equipmentType = typeSheet.getCell(0,1).getContents();
        Deck testCard= new Deck(equipmentSheet.getCell(0, 1).getContents(),equipmentType,Integer.parseInt(equipmentSheet.getCell(2,1).getContents()),Integer.parseInt(equipmentSheet.getCell(3,1).getContents()),Integer.parseInt(equipmentSheet.getCell(4,1).getContents()),equipmentSheet.getCell(5,1).getContents());

        return testCard;
```

That last line builds an object for the Deck constructor which looks like this:

```
public Deck(String cardName, String type, int cost, int value, int power, String image)
{
    super();
}
```

And Deck extends Card, where all the appropriate getters/setters are.

```
public Card(String cardName, String type, int cost, int value, int power, String image)
{
    this.cardName = cardName;
    this.type = type;
    this.cost = cost;        
    this.value = value;        
    this.power = power;
    this.image = image;
}
```

In my form class, this is my code I'm using to test if the image is working (hint: it's not.) It keeps throwing a NullPointerException

```
LoadCards test = new LoadCards();
test.LoadCards();
ImageIcon testImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(test.LoadCards().getImage()));
extraLineupSlot1.setIcon(testImage);
```

I need to figure out how I can correct this so that I can call the string from my spreadsheet that will represent a directory, the directory is stored in the image property of the Deck/Card object, and then I can call that property and change the icon associated with the different JLabels I've made.

Comment: What does `System.out.println` tell you?

Comment: When used in what way? I'm not sure I understand. Edit: If I do System.out.println(test.LoadCards().getImage()); I get a null as well. I'll do some tinkering and report back

Comment: Basically, put some `System.out.println` statements to verify the value is being read from the XML file, that the value is being set and that when you try to load the image, the path/name is what you expect

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried throwing in a few System.out.println() in there and attempted to print all of the properties of the testCard I was trying to use and all I'm getting are nulls and zeros. This would typically tell me it's not reading from the excel file, but even if I modify the object to return hard coded data instead of references to the xls file, it still gives me 0s and nulls.

Comment: Then I would take a look at your reading method and double check that it's actually reading the values from the excel as you would expect it...

Comment: It isn't the excel reading, it seems. What I meant before is, thanks to your suggestion of printing values to test, I found that what it's reading is irrelevant. Even if I type a generic string and tell it to return it - it's still giving me garbage data. I feel it's too late and I'm so tired that I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Looking at your `Deck`, none of the values you are passing it are being assigned to anything...

Comment: If I've done it right, they are all being assigned to the testCard Deck object, that testCard is being returned, and then when I call it and some of it's properties (.getImage or .getPower Etc) it is having the error. I'm going to sleep on it and come back after having time to think about it and rest..lol Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're able to get the list of strings, but you're having trouble getting the corresponding named resource. In this related [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad), a `List<String>` of names shares a common index with a `List<ImageIcon>` that serves as a cache of images stored as resources in a JAR. The method `getImage(int index)` returns an existing image from the cache or loads the image via `getResource()` for future reference. You might compare your approach. See the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) for more examples.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was asking but is still very useful info to a newb! Thank you very much!